# Why aren't bootnodes responding to my ping?

Tags: devp2p

I have impemented custom Ethereum node and I've been trying to `ping` bootnodes, but sometime in the past three months they stopped responding to me. The specific bootnode I've been trying to ping is

```
enode://979b7fa28feeb35a4741660a16076f1943202cb72b6af70d327f053e248bab9ba81760f39d0701ef1d8f89cc1fbd2cacba0710a12cd5314d5e0c9021aa3637f9@5.1.83.226:30303
```

The format of the ping is

```
(Ping version:3 
    Me:(EndPoint IP:52.4.20.183 TCP:30303 UDP:30303) 
    Them:(EndPoint IP:5.1.83.226 TCP:30303 UDP: 30303) 
    Expiration: 1527312518.72)
```

When RLP encoded this is

```
['\x03', ['4\x04\x14\xb7', 'v_', 'v_'], ['\x05\x01S\xe2', 'v_', 'v_'], '[\x08\xf0\x86']
```

I can send this type of ping to other nodes and I get responses, specifically `pong`s, as expected. However, when I send this message to the bootnodes, I get back nothing. Has there been a recent change to the P2P protocol? If so, what was it? It doesn't seem to be documented in any places I would expect.

**Are bootnodes running v5 of the discovery protocol without any documentation??**